# Unable to get property of undefined or null reference javascript

Tags: javascript, events

when I launch a function from my initialize function,  I got the message

"Unable to get property 'address_components' of undefined or null reference"

I first add a listener

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

here is my initialize function

```
function initialize() {
   document.getElementById('autocomplete').value =   city()+','+countryName();  
   autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
                                   {types: ['establishment','geocode']});

    fillInAddress();  --> this call does not work

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                    fillInAddress();  --> this call work when I change manually the value                   in                      the     field
                });
}
```

the following called function works when it is triggered by the above listener (place_changed)

```
function fillinAddress()

     var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
     console.log(place);    --> this gives undefined  when call from initialize function

     for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {  ..  --> this gives error 

     //Unable to get property 'address_components' of undefined or null reference
```

Any help?

Comment: Step 1: Step through the code in the debugger built into your browser to see what object is `null` or `undefined`. We can't just guess at which one it is (although the odds seem high it would be the result of one of the `getElementById` calls). The error message should be pointing you right at the relevant line, so it shouldn't be hard to figure out.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When I selected in the autocomplete list, whatever I choose, it works.  When I set the value by function as in this case, it does not work. When I console.log(autocomplete),  it is the whole object that is considered as undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the autocomplete to the function like

```
function initialize() {fillinAddress(autocomplete)}
function fillinAddress(autocomplete){console.log(autocomplete);}
```

Comment: still the same message.

Comment: When you call autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete

It possible that dont return some result, so autcomplete = null or undefined

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think that the google function does not work when I set a default value by function.